# Sitecore Event Queue - Can I delay events?

Tags: sitecore

Sitecore has a nice [event queueing system](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/API/Using%20Events.aspx) that is persisted to a database.
You can also [define custom events](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/API/Using%20Events/Defining%20Own%20Events.aspx).

I now need to be able to raise an event which has a delay before it's processed. Is this possible?

I could use some other queueing system ([ApacheMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html)?), but it would be nice to use the built in Sitecore one if possible.

Comment: I guess you have some misunderstanding about the purpose of queue. The main idea behind that is to communicate with other instances in a farm where you have several installations connected to one database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to delay an event directly. But there is a way to get the custom code you want executed with a delay.

You create your custom event. In the custom event handler use the Sitecore JobManager to execute a specific method which you want to start with a delay. By using the Sitecore JobManager you are able to delay the execution of the method by passing the additional parameter "InitialDelay".

```
var options = new JobOptions("JobName", "category", "Sitename", "Object Instance 
  which contains the method to execute", "Methodname")  
    { InitialDelay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5.0) };

JobManager.Start(options);
```

You can also use this to execute a method on your CD server with a delay, after triggering it from your CMS server by using remote events.

See also [this link](http://www.sitecore.net/deutsch/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/03/All-About-Jobs-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx) for more info about Sitecore jobs.

Comment: Ah, now that looks interesting. I'll see if I can use that. One potential issue is that my schedule might be several days in the future. Do you know if the Jobs are persisted anywhere, or are they just in memory?

Comment: As far as I see, the Jobs are save in memory by the JobManager

Answer (score 1):

To clarify one point, although Sitecore has various event models related to content editing and publishing, as well as pipeline events within the page lifecycle, it is wrong to say that "Sitecore has an event queuing system which is persisted to a database".

The idea behind the content editor events is that they occur in a specific order and in sequence, so 'delaying' an event would be <strike>an odd idea</strike> impossible. You can define scheduled tasks in sitecore (look under `/sitecore/system/Tasks`).  Perhaps you could create a custom event which could create or modify a sitecore item to hold some task information (call this your 'queue' if you like), then create a custom task (scheduled to run at predefined intervals) which would take items from this queue and process them.